# firebase recycler view crashing on scrolling down

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Hii I am trying to read data from firebase database and storage to Firebase recycler everything is working fine till I am scrolling the Recycler view down then app is crashing here is my code

MODEL CLASS

```
 package com.example.ace.park;

public class model {
    public String name,num,type,sno;


    public model(String name, String num, String type, String sno) {
        this.name = name;
        this.num = num;
        this.type = type;
        this.sno = sno;
    }

    public model() {
    }
}
```

Here is JAVA CLASS

```
package com.example.ace.park;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class dis extends AppCompatActivity {


    NavigationView navigationView;
    TextView textView;
    Intent intent;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model, displayAdapter> adapter;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference mDatabase,query;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dis);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myRecView);


        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("parkings");
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("parkings");

        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                .setQuery(query, model.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model, displayAdapter>(
                options) {
            @Override
            public displayAdapter onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler, parent, false);


                return new displayAdapter(v);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(displayAdapter holder, final int position, final model current) {

                holder.setName(current.name);
                holder.setTotal(current.num);
                holder.setType(current.type);
                holder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),current.sno,current.sno);

                holder.mview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(dis.this, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                });
            }


        };

        //Populate Item into Adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();



    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

Here is Adapter

```
package com.example.ace.park;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class displayAdapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public View mview;
    public displayAdapter(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mview = itemView;

    }
    public void setName(String name){
        TextView recName = mview.findViewById(R.id.recyclerName);
        recName.setText(name);
    }
    public void setTotal(String title){
        TextView t = mview.findViewById(R.id.recyclerTotal);
        t.setText(title);
    }
    public void setType(String type){
        TextView t = mview.findViewById(R.id.recyclerType);
        t.setText(type);
    }
    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image,String user){
        final ImageView iv = mview.findViewById(R.id.recyclerImg);

        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference().child("Parkings"+"/"+image);
        try {
            final File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
            storageReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e ) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Error in Adapter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }

    }

}
```

This is recycler layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerName"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textColor="#212020"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="@string/name_of_place"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerImg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:textColor="#615f5f"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerTotal"
            android:text="@string/tsp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/type"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerType"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Logcat is giving his error

11-21 20:37:32.885 9681-9681/com.example.ace.park E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ace.park, PID: 9681
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.example.ace.park.model
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:423)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:212)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:29)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:15)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:35)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:106)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:122)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:285)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:342)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:358)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:396)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

[this is image of database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9o7v.png)

Comment: This is because you are storing worng variable types into firebase, while some data might be with the correct type, some data is not.

Just delete the data from your database, rewrite it and try again , it should fix the problem if you were working on fixes

Comment: post a photo of your database structure

Comment: I have added a link of database structure image please check

Comment: post your current model class

Comment: I have posted model class at the top of this post I have just added getter and setter methods